# unable to launch unity app from 2d android app using intents in quest 2

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I am not able launch unity app from 2d android app using intents in quest 2, but  able to launch unity app from 2d android app using the same code on quest 1.

code :

Intent intent =
getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

LOGS:

2023-11-09 10:37:39.465   972-1020  VrDeviceManagerService  vrdevicemanagerserver                E  Permission denied: process 6512 (uid 10061) doesn't have the required permission: com.oculus.permission.SET_VR_DEVICE_PARAMS

2023-11-09 10:37:39.465   972-1020  VrDeviceManagerService  vrdevicemanagerserver                E  Permission denied: process 6512 (uid 10061) doesn't have the required permission: com.oculus.permission.READ_VR_DEVICE_PARAMS

2023-11-09 12:38:31.841 21001-21020 OsSdk                   com.Sify.IntentCall                  E  error getting shared memory region, memory type: HeadTracker, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'request throttled'

2023-11-10 14:57:54.076 29113-29137 OVRPlugin               com.Sify.IntentCall                  E  [GetBoundaryGeometry] ovrpBoundary_Outer is not supported (arvr/projects/integrations/OVRPlugin/Src/Util/CompositorOpenXR.cpp:7989)

com.Sify.IntentCall                  E  set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

2023-11-23 12:15:00.807  3222-5290  AnalyticsEvent          com...us.identitymanagement.service  E  could not set key=selection_args value=null

2023-11-23 12:15:00.514  3522-3522  QplClient               com.oculus.systemux:SystemUX         E  com.oculus.systemux: init() called multiple times.